# Open URL, Take Print Screen and Paste into Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to launch a URL, and then screen capture the IE window that opens (when the URL is launched it also starts a SmartCard Reader application), so I need it to either capture all windows open or the IE window and then either paste as an image into the cell below or save as a image to the C drive and then I can attach that file to the workbook.

I am trying to get this code to work for a particular screen that launches, I half got it working but it capturing the wrong application.

```
Sub Screenshot()

OpenClipboard (0&)
EmptyClipboard
CloseClipboard

Dim IE As Object
Dim hwnd As Long, IECaption As String
Dim fdate As Date


'~~> Change Status and unmerge
Range("B11").Value = "Running"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAT").Range("B18:D33").UnMerge

'~~> Launch URL

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://www.google.co.uk"

Sleep 5000

'~~> Get the caption of IE
IECaption = "Google - Internet Explorer"

Sleep 4000

'~~> Get handle of IE
hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, IECaption)

If hwnd = 0 Then
    MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    '~~> Maximize IE
     'ShowWindow hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
End If

DoEvents
'~~> Snapshot of window & Paste into Sheet location (Esc used to close an application popup screen)

Sleep 1000

keybd_event vk_Escape, 0, 0, 0

Sleep 2000

Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"

Sleep 2000

Application.SendKeys ("%{F4}")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SAT").Range("B18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


'~~> Tidy up and update status
Sheets("SAT").Range("B18:D33").Merge
Range("B11").Value = "Completed: Screen Captured"


End Sub
```

But i get a problem where it doesn't say ie screen not selected and then can't paste into B18 at the bottom, takes me to debug the "ActiveSheet.Paste" section.

It is so close, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at moving the IE window into focus by referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580606/how-to-take-screenshot-of-webpage-using-vba

Comment: @davidmneedham Thanks for that, i have managed to get it mostly working but still have some issues with pasting.

See my edited version above.

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("SAT").Range("B15")`?

Comment: @davidmneedham i still get Paste method of worksheet class failed and still not selecting the IE window